# Unable to get expected output in java threading with static var

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am trying to run below code and getting confused with output :

Its also sometime giving me output as below :
A : 7
C : 8
B : 7

Here how its possible that once static value has been changed to 8 and after that when B thread is going to run and going to print its value 7 ! I mean ***i*** is static variable then there is only one copy of it.

```
public class ThreadStaticTest implements Runnable {

    static int i = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadStaticTest obj = new ThreadStaticTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(obj);

        t1.setName("A");
        t2.setName("B");
        t3.setName("C");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that at any point in time there is only one copy of `i`? `i++` copies `i`, increments it and writes it back ... it isn't an atomic operation.

Comment: Also, thread A might read i as 7 and generate the string to print, then thread B might increment it and print 8, then thread A could print its string, containing 7.

Comment: @dhke : I hope here execution is like 
1) A has started running > reached to point i++ > incremented value to 6
2) B has started running > reached to point i++ > incremented value to 7
3) A prints value 7 
4) C has started running > reached to point i++ > incremented value to 8 > prints value 8
5) Now B starts printing value is still 7 !

Comment: @dhke : can you please correct me where I am going wrong in above execution flow ?

Comment: @JB Nizet : your comment seems valuable, its possible scenario :), B thread reach to point where value of i was 7 and created string to print but suddenly C thread incremented value to 8 and print 8 but as for B thread string was already built, it printed 7 for own.

Comment: @AmbitionFollwer You assume that `i++` is atomic, a single operation, which it isn't.

Comment: @dhke : I never assumed its i++ is atomic, but it has no relation with my output.

Comment: @AmbitionFollwer Hmm. No, you are right. But as said: there are more copies of `i` than one think (at least 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `i++` as three different operations:

1. fetch `i` (onto the JVMs stack, the JVM is a stack machine)
2. increment top of stack
3. store top of stack back into variable `i`.

Indeed, OpenJDK 8's javac compiles the `run()` method into:

```
public void run();
   Code:
      0: getstatic     #11                 // Field i:I
      3: iconst_1
      4: iadd
      5: putstatic     #11                 // Field i:I
```

Additionally, because `i` is not volatile, the JVM is allowed to optimize read access, that is, it can re-use the earlier value already on the stack for the `println()` call. So the `println()` call will typically see the value from the perspective of the current thread, not the stored value. And things can only get "worse" when the byte code is compiled into native code with access to multiple registers.

There *is* a `getstatic` invocation before the `println()` in byte code, but --as noted-- it will probably get optimized away. There's no guarantee what value will be read by it, anyway. You cannot even be sure that the value printed is the value seen by the same thread earlier.

Now, consider the following order of operations, assuming `i = 6`.

1. Thread A: fetches `i`
2. Thread C: fetches `i`
3. Thread A: increments `i`
4. Thread A: stores `i`
5. Thread B: fetches `i`
6. Thread B: increments `i`
7. Thread B: stores `i`
8. Thread C: increments `i`
9. Thread C: stores `i`

What do we get?

- A fetches `6`, and stores `7`, probably prints `7`.
- B fetches `7` and stores `8`, probably prints `8`.
- C fetches `6` and stores `7`, probably prints `7`.

You should get different result for each run, because there's nothing that guarantees this order of execution.

Comment: Yes this is also possible case ! :) so never trust java in threading case :D for even single statement ! we need synchronization or what !

Comment: @AmbitionFollwer That, but we've also had [atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) for quite a while, now.

Comment: Tried getAndIncrement() API of AtomicInteger but no luck ! They have used volatile internally, I have already tried that one. Still we can get above o/p sometime